# Sorting array of doubles extremely slow, and slower

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, double, qsort

I am trying to sort an array of doubles.  It is extremely slow:

```
double price[1000];

    void sortArrayOfDoubles(double price[ ], int length)    
    {   
        qsort(price, length, sizeof (double), compareDoubles);
    }
```

I am using this as the compare method, which is very slow.  Call it Method A:

```
int compareDoubles_SlowMethod(const void* elem1, const void* elem2)
{
    if(*(const double*)elem1 < *(const double*)elem2)
        return -1;
    return *(const double*)elem1 > *(const double*)elem2;
}
```

So then I tried this one, Method B, which is more than 3x slower than the other one.

```
int compareDoubles_EvenSlowerMethod(const void *x, const void *y)
{
  double xx = *(double*)x, yy = *(double*)y;
  if (xx < yy) return -1;
  if (xx > yy) return  1;
  return 0;
}
```

Is there anything faster?

Comment: How are you measuring this? What kind of performance are you seeing? What hardware are you running this on?

Comment: what OS, what compiler? how have you implemented qsort?

Comment: I am measuring using the VS2010 profiler.  I am running this on a dual cpu (Intel 5690's) workstation, with 12 physical and 24 logical cores, and 192 gigabytes (yes gigs, not megs) of ram, and a 1 tb solid state drive.  Qsort is the VS2010 C library routine.  Target is Windows7, 64bit

Comment: How long does it take to sort your array and how do you measure it? Starting a new process in windows is quite time-consuming, so if you measure the execution time of the entire program your measurement will be off.

Comment: Are you running optimizations on the code? I think they should be the same after optimization.

Comment: Which optimizations are you talking about that would help here?

Comment: @Klas: The issue is not starting a new process.  This sort takes place in a program where the sort routine is called millions of times. The sort is by far the most time-consuming element in the code.

Comment: @user994179 When you say "sort routine is called millions of times", by "sort routine" do you mean the sort function `qsort()` or the compare function candidates like `compareDoubles_SlowMethod()`.

Comment: The "sort routine" is the sortArrayOfDoubles() function.  Al this function does is call qsort().  Qsort() is the VS2010 library function, so I don't know how often it calls the compare() function.

Comment: @user994179 This issue is: is the price list, given to `sortArrayOfDoubles()` a _new_ set of `double` with no history to previous calls of `sortArrayOfDoubles()`?  `qsort()` assumes  little about present "sorted-ness" of the `price[]`.  If there is some connection between calls to `sortArrayOfDoubles()` and the list given to it, a different sorting method, or build-up-of-the-pricelist could be had that significantly improves performance.

Comment: Good point.  I simplified the code to post it here, but the array passed to sortArrayOfDoubles() is a subset of a larger array.  Each call to sortOfArrayOfDoubles() moves the subset forward by 390, so the qsort() has the advantage that most of the array has already been sorted.  So I guess it would even be slower if this were not the case (ie, if every array was completely unsorted).

Comment: Worst case for `qsort` is O(N^2). If the first element is chosen as pivot element then the worst case is when the array is already sorted.

Comment: Did you try my answer?  Curious if it got you better performance.

Answer (score 4):

I would write it as:

```
static int compareDoubles(const void *px, const void *py)
{
  const double x = *(double *) px, y = *(double *) py;

  if(x < y)
    return -1;
  return x > y;
}
```

This is essentially a mix of your two suggestions. Note that doing a callback just to compare a single value will never be optimally efficient. This is a drawback of how C's `qsort()` works; it would be best to inline the comparison inside the sort, but that's not possible in C.

Unless, of course, you implement the sorting algorithm yourself and tailor it for `double` values.

Comment: +1:  Look great except your routine name needs better marketing than "compareDoubles_EvenSlowerMethod".

Comment: @chux Thanks, that was a bit too much copy-paste. Changed.

Comment: Sorry, but this is only marginally better.  The profiler reports that the SlowMethod takes 7 time units to complete, the SlowerMethod takes 24, and your suggestion takes 20 units.

Comment: It is the "Exclusive Samples %" reported by the Profiler.  Whatever these measurement units are, it is clear that the slowest method is 3x slower than the fastest one.  And even the fastest one is dog slow.

Comment: @user994179 I'd up-vote your post again, if I could, for the simply fact that you are using a profiler to assess things. Often posts are too subjective. BTW: what is you list size?

Comment: The list size is either 390 doubles or (390 * 15) doubles. These are split evenly (meaning the same number of 390 lists as the (390*15) lists).

Comment: did you enabled compiler optimizations?  `gcc` generates exactly the some code for both functions.  Without optimizaitons, the "slower" variant might allocate `x` and `y` on the stack causing the slowdown.

Comment: Does enabling compiler optimizations make a difference since I am running this in the profiler?  If so, specifically what optimization should I make?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that getting the branch out of the function would improve its runtime.  For example:

```
int compareDoubles_noBranch(const void *x, const void *y) {
    return -1 * (*(const double*)x < *(const double*)y)
         +  1 * (*(const double*)x > *(const double*)y);
}
```

Probably it is not a good idea to do something like `const double x = *(const double*)x, ...` because of the memory/copy overhead if this is not optimized away by the compiler.  I'm not certain but I think that the inlined casts add no overhead, they just affect what CPU instructions are called on the memory `x` and `y` point to when the inequality operators are invoked.